# How to get RetryAdvice working for KafkaProducerMessageHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I'm trying to write `RetryAdvice` for `Kafka` handler; and fall back to saving to MongoDB as `RecoveryCallback`.

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaSuccessChannel")
public ExecutorChannel kafkaSuccessChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("kafkaSuccessChannel", asyncExecutor()).get();
}

@Bean(name = "kafkaErrorChannel")
public ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("kafkaSuccessChannel", asyncExecutor()).get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkaPublishChannel")
public KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> kafkaProducerMessageHandler(
        @Autowired ExecutorChannel kafkaSuccessChannel,
        @Autowired RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice) {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
    handler.setHeaderMapper(mapper());
    handler.setLoggingEnabled(TRUE);
    handler.setTopicExpression(
            new SpelExpressionParser()
                    .parseExpression(
                            "headers['" + upstreamTypeHeader + "'] + '_' + headers['" + upstreamInstanceHeader + "']"));
    handler.setSendSuccessChannel(kafkaSuccessChannel);
    handler.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(retryAdvice));
    // sync true implies that this Kafka handler will wait for results of kafka operations; to be used only for testing purposes.
    handler.setSync(testMode);
    return handler;
}
```

And then I configure the advice as follows in the same class

```
@Bean
public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(@Autowired RetryTemplate retryTemplate,
                                             @Autowired ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel) {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    retryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(kafkaErrorChannel));
    retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    return retryAdvice;
}

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    return new RetryTemplateBuilder().maxAttempts(3).exponentialBackoff(1000, 3.0, 30000)
            .retryOn(MessageHandlingException.class).build();
}
```

and finally I have a `Mongo` handler that would save the failed message to a certain collection

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkaErrorChannel")
public MongoDbStoringMessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler(@Autowired MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory,
                                                        @Autowired MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
    String collectionExpressionString = "headers['" + upstreamTypeHeader + "'] + '_'+ headers['" + upstreamInstanceHeader + "']+ '_FAIL'";
    return getMongoDbStoringMessageHandler(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter, collectionExpressionString);
}
```

I'm having hard time figuring out have I wired all of this correct as the test never seems to work, in the test class I **do not** setup any embedded kafka or connect to a kafka so that message publishing would fail, expecting this to trigger the retry advice and eventually save to dead letters collections in mongo.

```
@Test
void testFailedKafkaPublish() {

    //Dummy message
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", "value");
    // Publish Message
    Message<Map<String, String>> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(map)
            .setHeader("X-UPSTREAM-TYPE", "alm")
            .setHeader("X-INSTANCE-HEADER", "jira")
            .build();

    kafkaGateway.publish(message);

    //assert successful message is saved in FAIL collection
    assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "alm_jira_FAIL"))
            .extracting("key")
            .containsOnly("value");
}
```

I read we have to `setSync` to the Kafka handler for it to wait for results of kafka operations, so I introduced

```
@Value("${digite.swiftalk.kafka.test-mode:false}")
private boolean testMode;
```

to the Kafka Configuration; and in the test above I set it to true via the `@TestPropertySource` annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.main.banner-mode=off",
        "spring.data.mongodb.database=swiftalk_db",
        "spring.data.mongodb.port=29019",
        "spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost",
        "digite.swiftalk.kafka.test-mode=true",

})
```

I still cannot see any log out for Retry Advice executing or a failed message saved in Mongo. Another idea is to use `Awaitility` but I'm not sure as to what condition should I put in the `until()` method for it to work.

**Update**

Added debug logs for Kafka, I noticed the producer gets into a loop trying to reconnect with Kafka in a separate thread

```
2021-03-25 10:56:02.640 DEBUG 66997 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9999 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
2021-03-25 10:56:02.641 DEBUG 66997 --- [dPoolExecutor-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Kafka producer started
2021-03-25 10:56:02.666 DEBUG 66997 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:660) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:875) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:219) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:530) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

while the test reaches the assertion and hence it fails

```
    //assert successful message is saved in FAIL collection
    assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "alm_jira_FAIL"))
            .extracting("key")
            .containsOnly("value");
```

So it looks like the retry advice does not take over first the first two failures.

**Update 2**

Updated the configuration class to add property

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms:1000}")
private Integer productMaxBlockDurationMs;
```

and added the following line to `kafkaTemplate` configuration method

`props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, productMaxBlockDurationMs);`

that fixed it.

**Update 3**

As Gary says we can skip having to add all these props etc completely; I removed the following method from my class

```
@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, productMaxBlockDurationMs);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props));
}
```

and simply injected kafka config like so from properties thereby not having to write a Kafka template bean

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=1000
spring.kafka.producer.properties.enable.idempotence=true
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KafkaProducer`s block for 60 seconds by default before failing.

Try reducing the `max.block.ms` producer property.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_max.block.ms

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66768745Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66768745Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(template)
                            .topic("testTopic"), e -> e
                        .advice(retryAdvice))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(QueueChannel channel) {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        advice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(channel));
        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    QueueChannel channel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

}

interface Gate {

    void sendToKafka(String out);

}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: localhost:9999",
        "spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms: 500" })
class So66768745ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    Gate gate;

    @Autowired
    QueueChannel channel;

    @Test
    void test() {
        this.gate.sendToKafka("test");
        Message<?> em = this.channel.receive(60_000);
        assertThat(em).isNotNull();
        System.out.println(em);
    }

}
```

```
2021-03-23 15:16:13.908 ERROR 2668 --- [           main] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='test' to topic testTopic:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 500 ms.

2021-03-23 15:16:14.343  WARN 2668 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9999) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-03-23 15:16:14.343  WARN 2668 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9999 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-03-23 15:16:14.415 ERROR 2668 --- [           main] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='test' to topic testTopic:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 500 ms.

2021-03-23 15:16:14.921 ERROR 2668 --- [           main] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='test' to topic testTopic:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 500 ms.

ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to handle; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 500 ms., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=test, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, errorChannel=, id=d8ce277a-3d9a-b0bc-c14b-80d63ca13858, timestamp=1616526973218}], headers={id=1a6c29d2-f8d8-adf0-7569-db7610b020ef, timestamp=1616526974921}]
```

Comment: I added an example that works. Note that, for this particular error (can't fetch metadata), sync is not needed because the `TimeoutException` is thrown on the calling thread. You would neen `sync` for other (async) errors.

Comment: Thanks! @Gary Russel, tried your changes, also realized I can write flows to make it legible :-) but I still can't replicate the behaviour in your answer; would you please help me with pointing out where I'm going wrong in my code? Here's the Gist https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/087983f7eb3fe1d814c91adf9c54f4ce

Comment: It's hard to say; try setting org.apache.kafka log level to DEBUG  to see if it provides any clues - make sure the `max.block.ms` is applied in the produce config INFO log. If you still can't figure it out, strip it down to the bare minimum (like mine) and post the complete project someplace so I can run it locally. I changed my example to use an executor channel and it still works.

Comment: It looks like the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` does not take over; the Kafka Producer enters a loop of trying to reconnect and test eventually fails, added debug logs of Kafka and test.

Comment: Right, but that's the producer I/O thread, the `main` thread should time out like in my example; make sure the `max.block.ms` is properly configured (in the `ProducerConfig` INFO log). If you still can't figure it out, post a minimal project (like mine) someplace and I'll take a look what's wrong.

Comment: What I was missing was injecting the `max.block.ms` property to Kafka config apparently. so, adding `@Value("${spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms:1000}")` to the `KafkaHandlerConfiguration` and an additional `props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, productMaxBlockDurationMs);` in the `kafkaTemplate()` fixed it for me; this might be noob question but, adding properties in application `.yml` or `.properties` wont work here?

Comment: `application.yml/properties` are only automatically applied to Boot's auto-configured beans (producer factory in this case). If you define your own infrastructure beans, you have to fully configure them. It is generally not necessary to define your own producer factory bean, why not just use Boot's auto configured factory instead?