# How to add retry advice to kafka publishing IntegrationFlow

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I'm trying to setup retryAdvice if there is an error in publishing to kafka in my publisherFlow. I can't seem to find the correct configuration on how to get it working. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publisherFlow(CsvToEmailInteractionConverter converter, KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("publisherChannel")
                              .transform(converter, "transform")
                              .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                              .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, Constants.LOG_FLOW_CATEGORY, m -> "Payload: " + m.getPayload())
                              .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
                                           .topic(Constants.KAFKA_TOPIC), e -> e.id(Constants.ENGAGE_ACOUSTIC_ID))
                              // .routeByException(r -> r.defaultOutputChannel(MessageChannels.direct("standardFlowExceptionChannel").getObject()))
                              .get();
    }
```

I think the advice needs to go before the `handle()`?

Answer (score 1):

We don't see any retry configuration in your question, but see this one which might be exactly what you are looking for: [How to get RetryAdvice working for KafkaProducerMessageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768745/how-to-get-retryadvice-working-for-kafkaproducermessagehandler).

So, this is essentially what you need:

```
.handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
                 .topic(Constants.KAFKA_TOPIC)
                 .sync(true), 
            e -> e.id(Constants.ENGAGE_ACOUSTIC_ID)
                    .advice(retryAdvice))
```